# Calling Activity method inside Fragment that is not attached to Activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get a value from HomeActivity in my Fragment that doesn't have anything to do with HomeActivity. When I use

`selectedWorkout = ((HomeActivity) context).getSelectedWorkout();` 
in this case `context = getActivity();`

I get an error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.pttrackershared.models.Workout com.pttracker.views.screens.fragments.LandingFragment.getSelectedWorkout()' on a null object reference`

I also tried doing something like this:

```
Activity activity = getActivity();
   if (activity instanceof HomeActivity) {
       HomeActivity myactivity = (HomeActivity) activity;
       selectedWorkout = myactivity.getSelectedWorkout();
}
```

But, that simply doesn't work.

How would I go about getting this value ?

Comment: If that fragmet is not attached to the activity it means it is not belongs to that activity, so that code must not be into that activity. AND IT would be in the activity in which this fragment has been attached

Comment: @PankajKumar ty for your time to answer my question. That method is also used in another Fragment that is attached to HomeActivity. Basically the setSelectedWorkout is called in Fragment that is attached to HomeActivity, but I need to use getSelectedWorkout in Fragment that is not attached to HomeActivity.

Comment: You should either pass the value using _Bundle_ extras from the **HomeActivity** to the activity of the **LandingFragment** and/or using the _newInstance_ pattern.  Otherwise, you can have a singleton or a repository which holds such values in and they are accessible throughout the app. Have a look at [this article](https://medium.com/@programmerr47/singletons-in-android-63ddf972a7e7) to get a rough idea of the problem and solution

Comment: Move setSelectedWorkout method to utility class and use that method in both fragments.

Comment: Ty for the ideas-answers, I will get back to you with what I came up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your code is crashing because the `Fragment` is not attached to an `Activity`. So a quick fix would be to add a null-check like this:

```
Activity activity = getActivity();
if (activity != null && activity instanceof HomeActivity) {
       HomeActivity myactivity = (HomeActivity) activity;
       selectedWorkout = myactivity.getSelectedWorkout();
}
```

That said, accessing the `Activity` like this is not a good practice, as it couples the Fragment with a specific `Activity`. There are several better ways to approach it, like:

**Approach one:**
Make the `Activity` implement an interface like `SelectedWorkoutProvider`, move the getSelectedWorkout() method there and cast to the interface, not to `HomeActivity`

**Approach two:**
Pass the selected workout to the `Fragment` via arguments, like this:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("selected.workout", getSelectedWorkout());
LandingFragment fragment = new LandingFragment();
fragment.setArguments(args);
```

And then in the `Fragment` use:

```
getArguments().getString("selected.workout");
```

to get the value.

**Approach three:**
Use the `SharedPreferences` to save the data in the `Activity` and later get it in the `Fragment`. Please find the documentation for `SharedPreferences` [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use EventBus (or another similar library) and send an event from the activity to the fragment whenever a workout is selected